# Unexpected value "with" in the yml file in the GitHub actions pipeline

Tags: cypress, github-actions, pipeline

While running the Cypress tests, getting below error in GitHub action pipeline:
`The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/main.yml (Line: 44, Col: 9): Unexpected value 'with'`.
Could someone please advise how can we add `browser : chrome` in the yml file at the `with:` level.

```
name: Cypress Automation Tests
    
    on:
      pull_request:
        types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]
      push:
        branches: [develop]
    
    env:
      
      CYPRESS_BOOKING_FREE_USER_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_BOOKING_FREE_USER_PASSWORD }}
      
    
    jobs:
      install:
        runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
        steps:
          - name: Checkout
            uses: actions/checkout@v2
          - name: Install dependencies
            uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
            with:
              # just perform install
              runTests: false
    
      tests:
        runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
        needs: install
        steps:
          - name: Check out code
            uses: actions/checkout@v2
          # we re-install the dependencies
          - name: Install dependencies
            uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
            with:
              # just perform install
              runTests: false
    
          - name: Run Automation tests
            run: npm run cy:run -- --env grepTags="@Envtest1",ENV="staging"
            with:
              browser: chrome
          - name: Upload Results
            uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
            if: failure()
            with:
              name: cypress-screenshots
              path: cypress/screenshots
          - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
            if: always()
            with:
              name: cypress-videos
              path: cypress/videos
```

Comment: Is this what your actual file looks like? `on`, `env`, `jobs` should all have zero indentation.

Comment: Ok thank you very much, I have removed all of the unwanted indentation

Comment: There is a `run` step using `with` (the one called "Run Automation Tests"). The `with` subtype should only be used on a `uses` step to inform inputs.

Comment: I am able to run this way `run: npm run cy:run -- --env grepTags="@Envtest1+-@Failing",ENV="staging" --browser chrome` , but i would like to specify browser separately under with if possible !

Comment: Is there a way to accommodate that ? Please advise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `with` option isn't compatible with the run command you gave above it.

But it's ok to use `--browser` Cypress command line option, same as local `cy:run` command

Ref: [cypress run --browser](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line#cypress-run)

```js
cypress run --browser chrome
```

The pipeline (abbreviated to make it clearer)

```js
jobs:
  install:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    steps:
      ...

  tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    needs: install
    steps:
      ...
      - name: Run Automation tests
        run: npm run cy:run -- --browser chrome --env grepTags="@Envtest1",ENV="staging"
```

Answer (score 4):

@Paolo is correct, you can't use `with:` on a bash command step. But just to explain a bit more:

`with:` is only appropriate for steps that use another action.

For example, your "Check out code" step calls a standard action,

```yaml
steps:
  - name: Check out code
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
```

and you could add `with:` sections to provide custom input to that

The following is the top of Github's `checkout` action. The `inputs:` listed there correspond to the valid `with:` sections in your own workflow

```yaml
name: 'Checkout'
description: 'Checkout a Git repository at a particular version'
inputs:
  repository:
    description: 'Repository name with owner. For example, actions/checkout'
    default: ${{ github.repository }}
  ref:
    description: >
      The branch, tag or SHA to checkout. When checking out the repository that
      triggered a workflow, this defaults to the reference or SHA for that
      event.  Otherwise, uses the default branch.
  token:
    description: >
      Personal access token (PAT) used to fetch the repository. The PAT is configured
      with the local git config, which enables your scripts to run authenticated git
      commands. The post-job step removes the PAT.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your yml code looks ok to me. This is a formatting issue.

```yaml
name: Cypress Automation Tests
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]
  push:
    branches: [develop]
env:
  CYPRESS_BOOKING_FREE_USER_PASSWORD: '${{ secrets.CYPRESS_BOOKING_FREE_USER_PASSWORD }}'
jobs:
  install:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install dependencies
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
        with:
          runTests: false
  tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    needs: install
    steps:
      - name: Check out code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install dependencies
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
        with:
          runTests: false
      - name: Run Automation tests
        run: npm run cy:run -- --env grepTags="@Envtest1",ENV="staging"
        uses: ./
        with:
          browser: chrome
      - name: Upload Results
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        if: failure()
        with:
          name: cypress-screenshots
          path: cypress/screenshots
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        if: always()
        with:
          name: cypress-videos
          path: cypress/videos
```

Checked this on an online formatter -

[image: Yml formatter]

Comment: Thank you, Does this line here needs to be in single bracket ? `''` like this 
`run: 'npm run cy:run -- --env grepTags="@Envtest1",ENV="staging"' `

Comment: No it's not required.

Comment: Ok I will try again and let you know soon

Comment: Sorry its not working, error saying invalid type for `on `

Comment: there was a single quote in `on` I removed it. Can you try it now?

Comment: Sorry I have tried that too, still not working..

Comment: Updated the answer. changed the branches and types to an array.

Comment: Tried that, now its giving error: `The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/main.yml (Line: 31, Col: 9): Unexpected value 'with'`

Comment: How about instead of `with: chrome` you directly add the browser in the npm command `npm run cy:run -- --env grepTags="@Envtest1",ENV="staging --browser chrome`

Comment: Yes that way it is working, please see my comment above in another thread, but i wish to separate it with if possible, will ignore if that is too hard

Comment: One thing you can do is to create different npm commands under `package.json` under `scripts` and then use it here.

Comment: I have updated the answer with `uses` and under that I have mentioned `with: chrome`. Can you try that once.